# diffmerge location of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I wanted to [configure custom compare](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mitrik/2009/04/20/configure-diff-to-show-whitespace/) for TFS Source control. It needs location path of `diffmerge.exe` to execute from context menu command. But I couldn't find the path of `diffmerge.exe` in Program files. I searched for file in following locations but couldn't find it. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 professional.

```
"Program Files" > Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0, 12.0, 14.0 (separate folders)
"Program Files (x86)" > Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0 (separate folders)
```

Can anybody help with location of file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, the tool is named as `vsDiffMerge.exe`.

It's located under this path as default:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe`

[image]

Comment: I got it, Thank you. I was looking for diffmerge so couldn't find.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, I found it at this path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`